# React Native - Scan Local Network for Hosts

Tags: network-programming, raspberry-pi, react-native, wifi

is there any function, extension or tutorial which supports scanning of local network for hosts.

I like to scan the local networks for all Raspberry Pi computers.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lan scan library. But currently it has support for only Android. I myself is looking for a solution to scan ip cameras on local network. Here is a link 
https://github.com/Odinvt/react-native-lanscan
Also there is a objective C library if you can write binding for react.
https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan
I have only this much knowledge on topic right now. Will post further if i find something.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [How to build a port scanner with Javascript using React Native](https://shift8web.ca/2019/03/how-to-build-a-port-scanner-with-javascript-using-react-native/) for detailed tutorial, for react native library you can use [react-native-lan-port-scanner](https://github.com/gajjartejas/react-native-lan-port-scanner) which is based on this tutorial. This library offers convenient functionality for scanning LAN ports in your React Native projects.